# About vector space of polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about vector space. I need to prove, whether the set of polynomials of degree at least 3 is a vector space or not?

Comment: Did you try to check the axioms of a vector space?

Comment: Hint: The polynomials $x^3+x$ and $-x^3+3x+1$ have degree at least $3$.

Answer (score 2):

What is the degree of the $0$ polynomial? Assuming you can skirt this issue, you might note the lack of closure (in the manner suggested by André Nicolas). For example, here are two polynomials with degree at least three, for which the sum is a polynomial that does not have degree at least three:

$x^3 + x$ and $-x^3$. (Observe each has degree three.)

The sum of these polynomials is $x$, which is a polynomial of degree $1 < 3$.

**Answer:** Nope.